# Call a controller method from javascript in Component-Visualforce

Tags: javascript, controller, components, visualforce, apex

```
<apex:component>
 <apex:attribute name="l" description="l" type="double" assignTo="{!Received_L}"/>
  <apex:attribute name="varLng" description="t" type="double" assignTo="{!Received_T}"/>  
   //***** from here i want to call assignLocation()--------

</apex:component>
```

My Controller for Component

```
public class myController {
     public double Recieved_L{get;set;}
     public double Recieved_T{get;set;}

     public myController(){} //constructor        

    public PageReference assignLocation() {
        l=Recieved_L;
        t=Recieved_T;
        return null;
    }
```

I dont wanna call this method in constructor, I want to call myMethod() after page load

Comment: @eyescream as you answerd many of this type of questions, I am facing one problem of how to call my method assignLocation() in VF code, please suggest more specific with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to call Apex controller methods from javascript is by using  
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm

```
<apex:component>
 <apex:attribute name="l" description="l" type="double" assignTo="{!Received_L}"/>
  <apex:attribute name="varLng" description="t" type="double" assignTo="{!Received_T}"/>  
   //***** from here i want to call assignLocation()--------

  <apex:actionFunction name='myMethod' action='{!assignLocation}' />
</apex:component>
```

You will need a javascript code to invoke this action function either from your component or from outside the component in a visualforce page. Check the link on more in depth information on how to achieve this.